# Correct adding and UIViewController to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

Tonight one faced with this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    VC *vc = [[VC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [vc removeFromParentViewController];
    [self setView:vc.view];
}
```

and got a bomb:

```
uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason:
'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!
```

Q: How we can directly add `vc` and all its functionality to current `ViewController` without `AddSubView`?

Comment: Is loadView a method of a view controller? Then you create a new view controller and steal its view (vc.view) and assign it to self.view. What is the sense in that? What do you really want to achieve? Tell us more about what you are up to. I guess we find a proper way of achieving it. This piece of code so far does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Hermann, sorry, next time one will provide more details. It seems that problem is solved. Anyway thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your table view controller's view as a subview of the current view. You shouldn't call `removeFromParentViewController` on `vc` because that would essentially negate the line before. It's also a good idea to set the frame to match the parent.

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    [super loadView]; // this will create a basic view

    VC *vc = [[VC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    [self addChildViewController:vc];

    vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    vc.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];

    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: Neil, thank you, actually I did it the same way. But perhaps we have an approach to attach any another view without loading basic view? Or (it seems) we must load basic view firstly.

Comment: You must have at least a view that your parent view controller must own (and cannot be owned by your secondary view controller).

You could create an entire custom view if you wanted, instead of using `[super loadView];` like:

`[self setView:[[UIView alloc] init]];`